How to add clever tap to both iOS and flutter?
I have created an iOS flutter framework with the code flutter build ios-framework of my flutter project module. And I added this framework to my native iOS project. My issue is both these projects have clever tap plugin. Now I get this error in my native iOS project Multiple commands produce '/Users/MyPc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CounterApp-fwzwxbpgeztyavfsjfhytngyiksf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CounterApp.app/Frameworks/CleverTapSDK.framework'. How can we add this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
